# Unable to bind member_removed pusher event inside binding function of another event

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pusher

I'm subscribing to an event on a channel in Javascript like following:

```
pusher = new Pusher("APP_KEY")
channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel')

channel.bind('interview', function (data) {
  // do something here

  channel.bind('pusher:member_removed', function (data) {
    console.log("Removed from interview");
  });
});

channel.bind('pusher:member_removed', function (data) {
  console.log('Removed from anywhere');
});
```

In my Rails action I do something like following:

```
def interview
  Pusher['test_channel'].trigger('interview', {
    interview: 'some-id'
  })
end
```

I want both functions that are bounded to `pusher:member_removed` called when that event is fired.

However, when it is fired, only the function where "Removed from anywhere" is, called. The function with "Removed from interview" is never executed.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that channel.bind's callback behaviour won't additionally listen for other messages coming back. Could someone from Pusher elaborate?

The truly horrible thing you could probably do is do something like

```
pusher = new Pusher("APP_KEY")
channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel')
var inInterview = false;

channel.bind('interview', function (data) {
  inInterview = true;
});

channel.bind('pusher:member_removed', function (data) {
  if (inInterview) {
    console.log("Removed from interview");
  } 
  console.log('Removed from anywhere');
});
```

Comment: Whether that's truly horrible is a matter of opinion. It removes the nesting which some may say is a good thing. And it also means you only need to keep track of binding to the event once. *(Note: I have this Q on my backlog to look at)*.

Comment: Thanks for the input - let me know if there is a better way!